# How to debug PHP test files in Netbeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, phpunit, xdebug

When I Right Click > Debug File, the test runs successfully, but Netbeans can connect to xdebug.
I can confirm that debugging works in the normal Debug Project.

Is it even possible to debug a test file? If no, are there any alternatives?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to debug a separate file then you need to choose `Debug File` (shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + F5) instead of `Debug Main Project` (shortcut CTRL + F5).

Answer (score 2):

I copied the xdebug settings from my apache2/php.ini file to my cli/php.ini (Command Line Interface).

The file path on ubuntu 10.04 installed with apt-get is `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

My cli/php.ini file now has these settings:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

Then I can right click on the test file and select Debug (shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have got your IDE work with PHPUnit.

To make xdebug connect to PHP Netbeans IDE easily, I suggest you use *EasyPHP*. I'm using it and can debug my tests with IDE version 7. Just 1) open your test file, 2) call `Menu - Debug - Debug File` as `holodoc` has pointed out.

Comment: I'll give that a try. But do you think it's because of the framework(Yii) and configuration I'm using? I configured a bootstrap file and the phpunit.xml

Comment: Doesn't work. Are your files in the public folder or something?